# Get a defined row instead of empty result set: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a query that return rows even if they have no matching data in table. I know that an empty result set will be returned, but as my project necessity, I need to get a row in result set. It is acceptable though that the values are null. Below is my query:

```
select Demographic_Id, Total from school.Demographic_Profile where Demographic_Id=2
```

There is no data with Demographic_Id equal to 2. Still I need to get a result like this:

Demographic_Id | Total

```
     2         | NULL
```

Any suggestions would help a lot!

Comment: Is there a table that has all the demographic_ids you might need?

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since  you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

If you would get exactly one row or zero rows, then a trick is to use aggregation:

```
select 2 as Demographic_Id, max(Total) as Total
from school.Demographic_Profile
where Demographic_Id = 2;
```

Comment: This helped, but with little modification

Comment: select ISNULL(MAX(Demographic_Id),2) as Demographic_Id, Total from school.Demographic_Profile where Demographic_Id in (2)

Comment: @shaikirshadsharif . . . It can even be simplified further.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an outer join

```
select v.did As Demographic_Id, 
       Total 
from (values(2)) v(did)
LEFT JOIN school.Demographic_Profile ON Demographic_Id=v.did
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a CTE. The CTE will create a derived table. The `UNION ALL` will append one row, but only in case the query did not return any rows. Otherwise the query will return just as expected:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT object_id
          ,name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name='non-existent'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,NULL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE)=0
```

For your case try this:

```
DECLARE @id INT=2
WITH CTE AS
(
    select Demographic_Id, Total 
    from school.Demographic_Profile 
    where Demographic_Id=@id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT @id,NULL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select Demographic_Id, Total from
    (SELECT 1 as did
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as did
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as did) as innerQuery
    left outer join school.Demographic_Profile on did = Demographic_Id
```